# How to replace the non-lossless songs in my playlists with the lossless ones

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music, playlist, audio

Many songs in my playlists are not tagged as lossless when I play them.

I then go to the album and select display entire album. There I can see, that most of the time, there is a different version of the album available (one that is tagged as lossless).

I then have to delete the song from my library (losing all corresponding playlist entries) and then re-add the song from the lossless album.

And this for all songs that are not tagged as lossless (and there are many).

Anybody else have this problem?

Created from this reddit post : https://www.reddit.com/r/AppleMusic/comments/nw0rqx/do_i_really_have_to_manually_replace_the/

Comment: Frame challenge… what are you listening to these songs on? Unless it's 5+ grand's worth of hifi in the living room I defy you to be able to tell the difference. Lossless is becoming an interwebz meme. People are more concerned about the idea of lossy audio than they are about what it actually sounds like.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes although the sampling rate does matter. In my 40s I could tell the difference between 256k AAC or 320kps mp3  and lesser encodings so if your encodings are below this then you would want a better bit rate and might as well go lossless given the cost of storage now.